# Rounded edge border is clipped by textbox on top of the border

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

My Rounded edge border is clipped by textbox on top of the border

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
    <Border Margin="50,0,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="10">
        <TextBox Text="2345678" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image]

If the text is not in focus, it perfectly shows the rounded edge border.
[image]

How can I have the border to be intact, even when focused?

Comment: Set the TextBox's Margin, or put the Border on top of the TextBox.

Comment: Putting a margin to textbox will make the text smaller. And how to put the border on top of the textbox?

Comment: Actually, I can't even reproduce your issue. What exactly does it mean when the TextBox is "focused", taking into account that it is read-only? And what platform are we talking about, WPF or UWP?

Comment: It should be reproable on Either WPF or UWP, I use UWP. `TextBlock` will not allow you to select the text, while `TextBox` will. The reason is I want to let user to copy the text and at the same time I don't want the original text to be modified. So, "focus" means you click at the text. While I know that there are workarounds: putting `Padding` on the `Border` or set `Margin` to the `TextBox`, what other options do I have to keep the `Border` not clipped?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with WPF. Didn't try UWP. In WPF, the selected rectangle is behind the Border, although not clipped.

Comment: Got it and thanks! Let me put UWP tag then and please let me know if you have the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix is play with margins, this doesn't make the text smaller (but you might have the impression it is, because the text is a bit further from the border). Below is a screenshot without and with margin.

```
<Border Margin="50,0,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="2"
        BorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="10">
    <TextBox Text="2345678" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0"
             Background="Transparent" Margin="4,1"/>
</Border>
```

[image]

The more advanced scenario (but still quite simple) is changing the `TextBox`'s style by editing the template. You can start from the [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) as guidance. As your controls are readonly, you can simply remove the `PointerOver` and `Focused` `VisualState` `Storyboard`s content, or at least the animations on the BorderElement.

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
<VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
```

Comment: Sounds fair enough. Let me give removing the PointerOver and Focused VisualState a try